# Will it leak? FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance in custom singleton

Tags: android, firebase, memory-leaks, firebase-analytics

I still completely don't understand memory leaks. I have created custom singleton with `static` method:

```
public static AnalyticsHelper getInstance(Context context) {
    return analyticsHelper == null ?
            analyticsHelper = new AnalyticsHelper(FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(context)) :
            analyticsHelper;
}
```

and I want to know whether memory (activity) leaks will occur if I instantiate it in `Activity`. I'm not sure, because other Firebase tools works as `ContentProvider` and doesn't need `Context` when instantiating them. [Official docummentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/start/?gclid=CJ7n2NuYv9MCFUVmGwodB4YDUQ) won't help me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The accepted answer isn't correct.  Firebase Analytics (and all the other Firebase singletons that accept a Context) don't hold the same context that you passed to it.  It will use `Context.getApplicationContext()` on that Object behind the scenes to get a true singleton Context to hold for the lifetime of the object.  This is the way intelligent Android APIs will work that require a Context to hold indefinitely.

The only potential problem in the given code is the fact that it could possible create two instances of AnalyticsHelper when called in rapid succession from two different threads, but that is unlikely.

Comment: +1 for Doug answer. FirebaseAnalytics is singleton and its bound to the application context. It doesn't matter if the app keeps it or not. You can test this by calling FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance() from two different Activities or a Service and Activity and you will get the same instance each time.